# Is there a way to fit element inside Scrollview to its size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

My layout looks like this:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_part"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <RelativeLayout
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/main_content_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                    android:id="@+id/featured_vp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:overScrollMode="never" />

                <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                    android:id="@+id/view_pager_nav_fragment"
                    android:layout_below="@id/featured_vp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:minHeight="50dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <AnotherContent>...</AnotherContent>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Question is: which way is easiest to make RelativeLayout that holds my front content to fit scrollview?

I've try to achieve that programmaticly by change LayoutParanms of RelativeLayout but this way viewpager get all space inside layout, it kills my FragmentContainerView despite its min_heigt is 50dp.

Comment: Can you please share what is your expected output?? as image

Comment: if you are using ConstraintLayout then remove RelativeLayout and manage properly views with Constraint.